# User entitiy - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to setup the users and authentication with OAuth.
All my source code is here: https://github.com/Incybro/Spring-Blog

I installed lombok plugin in my Intellij IDEA, restarted IDE but there are some errors:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Spring-Blog\src\main\java\com\github\Spring\Blog\config\ResourceServerConfig.java
Error:(12, 12) java: class com.github.Spring.Blog.config.ResourceServerConfig is already defined in package com.github.Spring.Blog.config
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Spring-Blog\src\main\java\com\github\Spring\Blog\services\UserService.java
Error:(20, 53) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPassword()
  location: variable user of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Spring-Blog\src\main\java\com\github\Spring\Blog\SpringBlogApplication.java
Error:(27, 55) java: constructor Role in class com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.Role cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Error:(27, 73) java: constructor Role in class com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.Role cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Spring-Blog\src\main\java\com\github\Spring\Blog\services\CustomUserDetailsService.java
Error:(29, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getUsername()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(30, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPassword()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(31, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isActive()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(32, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isActive()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(33, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isActive()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(34, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isActive()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(36, 34) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRoles()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
```

In this lines:

```
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
```

```
public void save(User user){
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    repo.save(user);
}
```

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner setupDefaultUser(UserService service) {
    return args -> {
        service.save(new User(
                "user", //username
                "user", //password
                Arrays.asList(new Role("USER"), new Role("ACTUATOR")),//roles
                true//Active
        ));
    };
}
```

```
  @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return repo
                .findByUsername(username)
                .map(u -> new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                        u.getUsername(),
                        u.getPassword(),
                        u.isActive(),
                        u.isActive(),
                        u.isActive(),
                        u.isActive(),
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(
                                u.getRoles()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(r -> "ROLE_" + r.getName().toUpperCase())
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                        .toArray(new String[]{}))))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No user with "
                        + "the name " + username + "was found in the database"));
    }

}
```

Nothing is marked red. I can not start my app. Source code was copied from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOgCMtYMr2Q&list=PLcoE64orFoVsxAam_BuQBrNC8IO238SwH&index=2

Comment: The first error `Error:(12, 12) java: class com.github.Spring.Blog.config.ResourceServerConfig is already defined in package com.github.Spring.Blog.config` can be solved by deleting the outer class from `com.github.Spring.Blog.config.ResourceServerConfig` so only the annotated class is remaining in the file.

Comment: For the missing getters: did you enabled the annotation processing in the settings as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your `ResourceServerConfig` class. Use code below

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
```

instead of

```
public class ResourceServerConfig {

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
```